# Using static methods in static utility class in Java

Tags: java, oop, static

I have a program in Java which use an helper class with static methods in the main class, as described:

```
public class MainClass {

  public main() {

    String abc = "xyz";
    ResultA = Helper.methodA(abc);
    ResultB = Helper.methodB(ResultA);
  }
}
```

and the Helper:

```
public class Helper { 

  public static Result methodA(String s) {
    ...
  } 

  public static Result methodB(Result r) {
    ...
  } 

}
```

Now, as you can see from the structure, there is a dependency of data between methodA and methodB in the helper, and I don't create any instance of class 'Helper'. Is that a proper use in static method as I have no validation of data here? Is there a better known structure for that case?

Would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: *"Is that a proper use in static method"* You should not use static methods. They make the code using them harder to test and harder to extend.

Comment: Even if we're talking about helper methods , which should do certain operation and not to deal with wider aspects of the data, such as calculation methods etc?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having helper classes with static methods for performing small, repetitive tasks. I'm not saying I advocate their use but they have a place. Its not easy to answer your question with the given example. If methodA and methodB just performed some arithmetic then I would say yes, they are fine.

Comment: *"Even if we're talking about helper methods"* I for myself answer this with Yes. The question is: when is a method a "Helper" and when not? My answer is: there is no such thing like a "helper method". Any method supports the business case, that's why it is in the program in the first place...

Answer (score 0):

Better to use static methods as and when really needed.                        Utility classes having the static methods which share the common behaviour across the project. 
If your method resides in the Utility class , then go ahead. Otherwise create object and access via in it.